# Perl split string by semi colon not glob

Tags: perl

I have a file:

1:2;3;4

and I want to splot that file into its constuitiemt parts which are delimited by a semicolon

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = shift @ARGV ;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";

my @splitoncolong = split /;/, $fh ;
foreach my $wap (@splitoncolong) {
         print $wap ;
}
```

and I get this

```
GLOB(0x238947c)
```

what I want is this :

```
1; 
2; 
3; 
4;
```

Comment: You're never actually reading any data from the file handle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to read from your file handle.

```
#                              V   V
my @splitoncolong = split /;/, <$fh>;
```

The way you had it it tried to split the file handle object, which when stringified by `split` turns into the glob reference representation you are now seeing. It splits on `;`, which yields one result, the string `GLOB(0x...)`, and puts that in your list.

Comment: Also note that the `;` is called a _semicolon_, not a _colong_. A better name for that variable would be `@fields`.